# Integer column has decimal places in DBASE IV dbf

Tags: c#, oledb, jet, dbase

Tried to search everywhere online but didn't find an answer.

I created the table with the connection and code below:

```
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+ FilePath +";Extended Properties=dBase IV";

    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + FileName + " ([JNL] VarChar(4), " +
                                                                     "[LINE] VarChar(5), " +
                                                                     "[TYPE] VarChar(6), " +
                                                                     "[DRACC] VarChar(9), " +
                                                                     "[CRACC] VarChar(9), " +
                                                                     "[EXPDRACC] NvarChar(12), " +
                                                                     "[EXPCRACC] NvarChar(12), " +
                                                                     "[DRSTITLE] VarChar(9), " +
                                                                     "[CRSTITLE] VarChar(9), " +
                                                                     "[DOCDATE] DateTime, " +
                                                                     "[REF] VarChar(8), " +
                                                                     "[DRAMT] Integer, " +
                                                                     "[CRAMT] Integer, " +
                                                                     "[LARGE] VarChar(7), " +
                                                                     "[DESC] VarChar(6), " +
                                                                     "[TRACE] VarChar(6), " +
                                                                     "[TRNDR] VarChar(7), " +
                                                                     "[TRNCR] VarChar(7), " +
                                                                     "[PARTS1] VarChar(8), " +
                                                                     "[PARTS2] VarChar(8), " +
                                                                     "[PARTS3] VarChar(8), " +
                                                                     "[PARTS4] VarChar(8), " +
                                                                     "[PARTS5] VarChar(8))";
```

EDIT: DRAMT and CRAMT columns always have decimal places when viewed in excel.
How do I resolve this kind of issue?

Comment: Nothing wrong with code.  It is the way you are viewing the data.

Comment: @jdweng Does that mean when viewed in excel the formatting is decided by excel itself?

Comment: Excel defaults to General Formatting which attempts to guess at the format of the data and often guesses wrong.  Actually it is not Excel that guesses it is the driver either Jet or Ace that makes the wrong decisions.

Comment: @jdweng so what can you suggest what driver to use other than Jet/Ace?

Comment: There is no issue.  Just ignore the decimal places in excel, they don't exist in database.